# PNG compression using WuQuantizer not woring

Tags: c#, png, image-compression

I use following code to compress png.

```
 Bitmap bmp1;
                    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        byte[] imageData = webClient.DownloadData(inputPath);
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
                        {
                            bmp1 = new Bitmap(stream);
                        }
                    }

                    if (bmp1.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                    {
                        // Convert the image to a 32-bit ARGB format
                        Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
                        {
                            gfx.DrawImage(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height));
                        }
                        bmp1 = newBmp;
                    }


                    var quantizer = new WuQuantizer();
                    using (var quantized = quantizer.QuantizeImage(bmp1))
                    {
                       
                        quantized.Save(outputPath, ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
```

But the output Image size is higher than the input PNG image, What is the issue here?

Comment: BMP files are not compressed. PNG files are.